# How to disable function calls for some time

Tags: python

I'm relativity new to Python, having only worked with it about a month or so, and I wanted to make a text rpg on Python 2.7.2. So for some commands, such as mining or fishing for example,I wanted to have some time after they used the command where they can't use the command again for a specific period of time.

```
while True:
command = raw_input("Say something")
if command = "mine":
    print "You found 2 Rocks! etc."
```

I want to make it so that you can only use the command every 1 minute, for 
example. 
If the time wasn't finished yet, it'll print

```
print "Please wait a moment(%s seconds remaining)" % timeleft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should probably use Python3. But that's up to you. My answer uses Python3 but you should be able to convert to Python2 easily.

You could create a dictionary where the key is the command and the value is the timestamp of when the command was last used. For example:

```
import datetime

commands = {}

while True:
    cmd = input("Enter command: ").lower()
    if "quit" == cmd:
        break

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Command already used at least once?
    if cmd in commands:
        # Check if time has elapsed
        diff = now - commands[cmd]
        if diff.seconds < 10:
            # Time has not elapsed - print warning and start loop over
            print(f"Wait {int(10-diff.seconds)} more seconds before using that command")
            continue
    # If this line is reached, it's ok to use the command
    print(f"Using command: {cmd}")
    # Reset time for this command
    commands[cmd] = now
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses Python 3.6

You could use a closure: In this case, via the use of a named argument with a mutable default value. The last time the function executed is stored, and compared to the current time when called again. If the time difference is too short, the function returns without executing the code.

```
import time


disable_time = 5


def do_stuff_then_disable_for_a_while(stamp=[time.time()-disable_time]):
    """will disable for disable_time after each successful use"""
    if time.time() - stamp[0] > disable_time:
        stamp[0] = time.time()
        print("doing stuff")

    else:
        print("currently disabled")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:

        do_stuff_then_disable_for_a_while()
        time.sleep(1)
```

#### output:

```
doing stuff
currently disabled
currently disabled
currently disabled
currently disabled
doing stuff
currently disabled
currently disabled
currently disabled
currently disabled
doing stuff
```

## Use as a decorator:

This is a frequent enough problem to try to give it a more general solution: The following allows to decorate a function, to set the time during which it is disabled:

```
import time
from functools import wraps


class _Disabled:
    """helper class for a decorator that disables
    a function for some time delay"""

    def __init__(self, disable_duration):
        self.first_call = True
        self.disable_duration = disable_duration
        self.last_called = time.time()

    def __bool__(self):
        """return True if disabled, False otherwise
        Attention: has a side effect with consequences:
        ==>> upon first time called, sets first_called flag to false
        """
        if self.first_call:
            self.first_call = False
            return False

        _disabled = time.time() - self.last_called > self.disable_duration

        if _disabled:
            self.last_called = time.time()
            return False
        return True


def disable_for_a_while_after_called(disable_time=5):
    """Decorator factory that modifies the decorated functions so that
    after execution, they are disabled for some time, before they can run
    again
    """
    def _disable_for_a_while_after_called(f):
        must_not_call_function = _Disabled(disable_time)

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args):
            if must_not_call_function:
                r = None
            else:
                r = f(*args)
            return r
        return wrapped
    return _disable_for_a_while_after_called
```

#### Example usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    @disable_for_a_while_after_called()
    def do_stuff():
        return "doing stuff"


    @disable_for_a_while_after_called(disable_time=2)
    def do_other_stuff():
        return "doing other stuff"


    @disable_for_a_while_after_called(disable_time=13)
    def do_infrequent_stuff():
        return "doing infrequent stuff"


    for s in range(100):
        a = do_stuff()
        b = do_other_stuff()
        c = do_infrequent_stuff()
        print(f"{s}: {a if a is not None else ' '*11}, "
              f"{b if b is not None else ' ' * 17}, "
              f"{c if c is not None else ''}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

#### output:

```
0: doing stuff, doing other stuff, doing infrequent stuff
1:            ,                  , 
2:            , doing other stuff, 
3:            ,                  , 
4:            , doing other stuff, 
5: doing stuff,                  , 
6:            , doing other stuff, 
7:            ,                  , 
8:            , doing other stuff, 
9:            ,                  , 
10: doing stuff, doing other stuff, 
11:            ,                  , 
12:            , doing other stuff, 
13:            ,                  , doing infrequent stuff
14:            , doing other stuff, 
15: doing stuff,                  , 
16:            , doing other stuff, 
17:            ,                  , 
18:            , doing other stuff, 
19:            ,                  , 
20: doing stuff, doing other stuff, 
21:            ,                  , 
22:            , doing other stuff, 
23:            ,                  , 
24:            , doing other stuff, 
25: doing stuff,                  , 
26:            , doing other stuff, doing infrequent stuff
27:            ,                  , 
28:            , doing other stuff, 
29:            ,                  ,
```